# How to add the return value of a function to the DOM as text that displays in a div element after an event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I have a function which returns a string. I want that string to show up in a div, after a button is pressed in a different div.

```
<div >
   <button id="something"> something </button>
</div>
<div id="results">
   want result to show up here
</div>
```

```
const something = document.querySelector('#something');
something.addEventListener('click', someFunction);

function someFunction(a, b){
......
// returns a string and takes two parameters, one parameter from the user 
}

const results = document.querySelector('#results');
// how to add return value of someFunction as text in the #results div?
```

Comment: You need to use the string value returned by `someFunction` and manually set the return value as the content inside `div#results` element. You also haven't passed any argument to `someFunction` but you have defined it to take 2 parameters.

Comment: the problem is that someFunction doesn't recognize my arguments inside add.EventListener().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to print the value returned by `someFunction` and show it inside the `result` element.

You can restructure your code like this -

```
const something = document.querySelector('#something');
const results = document.querySelector('#results'); // your result div

// you missed the function keyword
function someFunction(a, b) {
  ......
  // returns a string and takes two parameters, one parameter from the user 
}

something.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const resultText = someFunction(a, b); // you need to give the value for a nad b
  result.textContent = resultText;
});
```

Also, in your approach, you are not passing any argument to `someFunction`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't pass any arguments to someFunction because I thought the problem required using callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me get my program to work as intended!